# Understanding the meaning of $P[X=i\wedge Y=j]$

Tags: probability

Let $\{(,):1\leq ,\leq 6\}$ be the sample space of rolling a die twice uniformly at random . Specify whether if we define two random variables $X(i,j)=i$ and $Y(i,j)=j$  why
$P[X=i\wedge Y=j]=\frac{1}{36}?$

Comment: You have not actually defined a probability measure on your space, so cannot answer your question.  But if $P[X=i\wedge Y=j]=\frac{1}{36}$ (counting measure with all possible outcomes equally probable) then summation will give $P[X=i] =\frac 16$ and $P[Y=j] =\frac 16$, and this implies $P[X=i\wedge Y=j]=P[X=i] P[Y=j]$ which is the definition of independence.  You do not need $P[X=i\wedge Y=j]=\frac{1}{36}$ for all $i,j$ and some alternatives will lead to independence while others will not

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Surely you meant independence  (and fairness) of the rolls to be assumed in the problem.  It's not a mathematical necessity.  The die could be weighted, or there could be some mechanism linking the roles.  If you didn't mean to assume independence and fairness, you need to clearly indicate what you are assuming instead.

Comment: @Henry My question is just why $P[X=i\wedge Y=j]=\frac{1}{36}?$ could you interpret it?

Comment: The interpretation of $P[X=i\wedge Y=j]=\frac{1}{36}$ is that each of the $36$ possible outcomes is equally likely.  It is an assumption of fair dice

Comment: @Henry I try as follow: $P[X=i\wedge Y=j]=P[X=i\cap Y=j]$ so $X=i\cap Y=j$ is pairs $(1,1),(2,2),\dots,(6,6)$. As a result $P[X=i\wedge Y=j]=P[X=i\cap Y=j]=\frac{6}{36}$. Where is my wrong?

Comment: No, actually $X=i\bigcap Y=j$ defines just _one_ pair, $(i,j)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Could you explain more? Thank you.

Comment: Your $\frac{6}{36}$ is $P[X=Y]$ or more verbosely $P[X=1\wedge Y=1]$ $ +$ $P[X=2\wedge Y=2] $ $+$ $P[X=3\wedge Y=3] $ $+$ $P[X=4\wedge Y=4] $ $+$ $P[X=5\wedge Y=5] $ $+$ $P[X=6\wedge Y=6] $  or if you prefer $\sum\limits_{i=1}^6 P[X=i\wedge Y=i]$

Comment: @Henry Thank you. Now could we conclude that $P[X=i,Y=j]$ refer to a pair $(i,j)\in\Omega$ such that $X(i,j)=i$ and $Y(i,j)=j$?